# Grey/diffuse text on Mac OS X Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This is the website](http://ldlocal.web44.net/contacto.html).

I have an strange "text display" error that it's only happenning on **Chrome in Mac OSX**. I have tried it in 5 iMacs and Macbook and all show the text in a bad way. I know in Windows Chrome it looks good...

I have a submenu that is high enough to be over a API Google Map I put on the page. The problem is that if the submenu is over the map, the text (**which has white css property**!) changes to a **grey diffuse style**.

Here is the CSS:

```
#contact_map{
    width: 537px;
    height: 340px;
    float: left;
}

#map_canvas{
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
}

#header #header_box ul#mainnav ul.submenu.big .submenu_big_box li a {
      text-transform: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: white;
}
```

And this is the problem:

[image]

How it should look (just white font):

[image]

You can see that is the Google map the one that is making the error if you remove the `float:left` property from `#contact_map`. The maps goes down and the the text shows in it's white color.

I have tried with all other browsers and it seems it only happens on Chrome in Mac OSX, any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I´m on Mac OSx Lion and I see the problem too, let me check it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks odd to me on a MBP with Chrome. I think this is what you want:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px
```

Source: [Beefing Up Dull Text in WebKit](http://css-tricks.com/beefing-up-dull-text-in-webkit/)

With that, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @diego You're welcome. If you read the source article linked, it indicates you may not need to do this if you can fix another CSS issue that it discusses however to get it working now this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on OS X 10.7 with Chrome and it looks white for me. These are my calculated styles:

```
color: white;
cursor: auto;
display: inline;
float: none;
font-family: avenirnext_lt_pro_ultlightRg;
font-size: 12px;
height: auto;
line-height: 15px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
width: auto;
```

Perhaps you can check your calculated styles in chrome to make sure they are ok?